# Google Swiffy iPad Button double click issue

Tags: javascript, html, flash, google-swiffy

I have recently converted some flash files to HTML5 using the google swiffy converter. These files are working great within a desktop browser but when it comes to testing on an iPad i am having some issues.

The problem I am having is with buttons. My buttons are showing up correctly however when you tap on them they are just being highlighted and not actually calling the click event. If i then click the highlighted button again the click event fires.

Is there any way to solve this problem as it is very frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was with this.

The way that the buttons were created was that they were Movie Clips,  if i changed them to be buttons and then exported and converted the buttons started working properly.